# spacing issue using mathit with unicode-math added

Tags: fonts, unicode-math

I like to use `Asana Math` when compiling using lualatex to pdf.

But to use `Asana Math` I have to load `unicode-math` in order to use `\setmathfont` command to load the font.

I noticed when adding `unicode-math` the space is lost after `\mathit`.

When I comment out `unicode-math` and `\setmathfont` the space comes back.

Why does using `unicode-math` makes the space after `\mathit` go away? Is there is something wrong with my usage of these package, and is there a workaround so that I can use Asna math but still keep the space after `mathit` as it was before?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} %needed to use \setmathfont
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathit{\_C1} {\rm e}^{3 x} \sin \left(2 x \right)+\mathit{\_C2} {\rm e}^{3 x} \cos \left(2 x \right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Replacing the above code with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathit{\_C1} {\rm e}^{3 x} \sin \left(2 x \right)+\mathit{\_C2} {\rm e}^{3 x} \cos \left(2 x \right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The space is larger.

This image shows the difference

[image]

**Update**

Here is test case with suggestion from answer below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[mathit=sym]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]    
\begin{document}    

\begin{equation}
\mathit{\_C1} {\rm e}^{3 x} \sin \left(2 x \right)
\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

And

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\symit{\_C1} {\rm e}^{3 x} \sin \left(2 x \right)
\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using TL 2020.

ps. The code inside the equation above was autogenerated by external software and I did not write it myself.

Comment: \rm is a old command.

Comment: I'm not sure how come that software that claims to generate LaTeX code still outputs rubbish like `{\rm e}` which has been deprecated for more than a quarter of a century. And I bet this software is less than 25 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load `unicode-math`, it sets `\mathit`, `\mathrm`, `\mathbf` and so on to the main text fonts.  This means that, when you load `\mathit`, you get italic correction.

If you want to insert some extra space, you might add a `\,` or wrap the term in `\mathop`.

You could also try changing `\mathit` to `\symit`, or loading `unicode-math` with the package option `mathit=sym`, either of which will load the Italic math letters from the math font instead.  However, these do not include underscore or digits.

This formatting, which you say is machine-generated, is extremely poor.  For one thing, `\rm` is obsolete and you would want to use `\symup` or `\mathrm`.  For another, Asana Math is based on Palatino, so you would want to set the text font to Palatino (or Pagella) to match it, rather than using the default Latin Modern.  If you are typesetting constants upright, you are probably using ISO style and might also want to load `math-style=ISO`.  Using `\mathit` here is not what I would recommend at all. If those terms are program variables, they might be `\mathtt` or `\mathsf`.

Comment: Thanks. When you say `or loading unicode-math with the package option it=sym` do you mean like this `\usepackage{unicode-math}[it=sym]` ? if so, I just tried and the space is stil not same as without unicide.  Same when I replace `mathit` with `symit`. I will post screen shot if you like.

Comment: @Nasser package options always come before the package name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  `\usepackage[it=sym]{unicode-math}` gives error.  Will mention this in my post.

Comment: @Nasser see the package documentation `mathit=sym` (table 4, page 11)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. It looks like `\usepackage[mathit=sym]{unicode-math}` will do for now even though the space seems a little larger in default case. But will live with it,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the correction. `mirrors.ctan.org` seems to be down.

Comment: @Nasser The space wouldn’t be exactly the same, because you’re using a different font. However, you can add space or kerning if you want.